# How do I convert a SQL Server datetime to a C# int64 in ADO.NET?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, c#-4.0, long-integer, int64

I would like to read from a datetime field in SQL Server and store it as a int64, as datetime is stored as 64 bits in SQL Server. Would I do something similar to this?

```
DateTime dt = sqlDataReader.GetDateTime(0);
byte[] bt = BitConverter.GetBytes(dt);
// unfortunately, GetBytes() does not take DateTime as an argument
long ldt = (Convert.ToInt64(bt[0]) << 56)
         + (Convert.ToInt64(bt[1]) << 48)
         + (Convert.ToInt64(bt[2]) << 40)
         + (Convert.ToInt64(bt[3]) << 32)
         + (Convert.ToInt64(bt[4]) << 24)
         + (Convert.ToInt64(bt[5]) << 16)
         + (Convert.ToInt64(bt[6]) << 8)
         + (Convert.ToInt64(bt[7]));
```

Comment: Why would you do something like that? What's the reason?

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading/misunderstanding things but [Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) will cost 64 bits and [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) costs 64 bits so ... the gain is what?  I mean if it's just an exercise in programming, carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Get the date value as a unixtimestamp-style INT directly from SQL server:

```
select datediff(second, {d'1970-01-01'}, yourdatefield) as seconds
```

It'll save you all the bit fiddling in your app.

If you want to implement a mysql-style "unix_timestamp()" function in tsql, this blog entry shows how to create a function for it: http://skinn3r.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/t-sql-datetime-to-unix-timestamp/

Comment: true, but only 32bit unixes. 64bit time_t's are fairly widespread already. And it's easier to do a 32bit->64bit int conversion than it is to do a datetime->int conversion in c#

Answer (score 0):

Why not `dt.ToBinary()`?

Using `System.GC.GetTotalMemory`, it seems that `DateTime` uses 212 bytes while `long` uses 8 bytes.